# I can't test with phpunit: Cannot open file "autoload.php"

Tags: php, phpunit, wamp, composer-php

---

### Config :

- PHPUNIT: 4.5.0
- PHP : 5.4.12
- Server: Wamp
- Composer: version 1.0-dev 2015-02-17 21:55:44

---

### composer.json :

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.5.*"
    }
}
```

---

### autoload.php :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");

require __DIR__.'/vendor/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Hangman' => __DIR__.'/src',
    'Symfony' => __DIR__.'/vendor',
));

$loader->register();
```

---

### phpunit.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
        >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="hangman">
            <directory>tests/Hangman/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory>vendor</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

---

### Problem :

I executed : `phpunit --bootstrap autoload.php tests`

My Error : `Cannot open file "autoload.php"`

Can you help me ?

Comment: You don't need to specify the bootstrap file when executing phpunit, as it's already defined in the phpunit.xml file. Try using an absolute path.

Comment: try to execute composer dumpautoload in command prompt or git bash

Answer (score 7):

I am working with PHPUnit 7 and basis on that I have mentioned solution in the below which is tested and working 100%

If you are windows user then type following on cmd:
"vendor/bin/phpunit" --bootstrap ./vendor/autoload.php ./tests/EmailTest

Make sure I have updated ./ before vendor and tests.

Answer (score 6):

You could give `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"` a try in your `phpunit.xml`. Then PHPUnit and your Tests would use the Composer Autoloader.

Or you could require the Composer Autoloader (in addition to Symfony's UCL) in your `autoload.php` by adding `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`. This results in two autoloaders being registered.

Then run:

1. `composer update` - to fetch dependencies and rebuild the autoloading files
2. `phpunit` - to execute a test run

You don't need to run `phpunit` with `--bootstrap`, because the directive is already set in your phpunit.xml.

---

I think your folder layout is not right.
You start with this:

```
c:\wamp\www\yourproject
  \src
  \tests
    \- phpunit.xml.dist
  \vendor
  \composer.json
```

1. add `phpunit` to the `require-dev` section of your composer.json
2. add `"bin-dir" : "bin"`, so that phpunit.bat lives in `c:\wamp\www\yourproject\bin\phpunit.bat` and not in `c:\wamp\www\yourproject\vendor\bin\phpunit.bat`
3. `composer install` or update
4. exec `c:\wamp\www\yourproject\bin\phpunit.bat -c c:\wamp\www\yourproject\tests\phpunit.xml.dist`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but that didnt work. I still have the same problem. C:\wamp\www\phpunit\vendor\bin>phpunit autoload.php tests
Cannot open file "autoload.php".

Comment: It's not `phpunit autoload.php tests`, just `phpunit`, if you have a xml config file in the same folder. Also the folder structure (`C:\wamp\www\phpunit\vendor\bin`) indicates, that you are not in your project (unless you want to work on phpunit itself). In other words: your project should live in `C:\wamp\www\yourproject` and the autoloading lives at `C:\wamp\www\yourproject\vendor\autoload.php`.

Comment: I faced this issue after upgradig to Laravel 5.5 from 5.4. Your suggestion solved my problem.